# How do I filter tables while creating entity classes from database in netbeans?

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, entity

The database have 5000+ tables.

I'm creating entity classes from database in **NetBeans**, it lasts an hour.
I will select 10 Tables from these. But bringing it all tables.

I know how create entity classes:

[image]

Is there a way to speed up? How do I filter tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97739) submitted to NetBeans, but for now it doesn't look like you can filter the tables.

> Martin Balin 2016-07-07 08:56:00 UTC
>
> This old bug may not be relevant anymore. If you can still reproduce it in 8.2 development builds please reopen this issue.
>
> Thanks for your cooperation,
> NetBeans IDE 8.2 Release Boss
>
> Comment 14 vasster 2016-09-04 13:28:49 UTC
>
> Yes it still exists in nightly-201609040002. Very slow retrieving of lots of tables. It seems that it may take half an hour to retrieve 3000 tables on an Oracle schema (jdbc7 driver).
>
> I don't think it is actually a bug (it's not broken) but an enhancement request.
> The past ideas are good candidates. Let it retrieve just the list of table names on schema to show and do actions on the next steps of the wizard for tables that are selected by the user.

Comment: How are you solving this problem?

Comment: I haven't solved it, I was just curious about your question so I searched a bit.